# Submitting GPGS events from server

Tags: android, mobile, google-play-games

I'm writing a game that use Google Play Game Service's quests and events system - https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quests.

Game will use it on Android devices, but I want to submit certain events from server. I found web rest api for this https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/events/record, but it's not clear to me how to proceed with authorization.

Can i somehow send all needed authentication info from client to my server, to use GPGS' rest api in future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is informally called **hybrid authorization**, and the best way to do that is to send an **Authorization Code** from the Android app to your web server.  The web server can then exchange the code (one time) for an **Access Token** and a **Refresh Token**.  This is not specific to games and is something that many apps using Sign-In with Google do all the time.

The [Google+ Haiku+ Sample](https://developers.google.com/+/haikuplus/android) shows and example of this flow. The specific pieces you may want to look at (in the Android app) are `MainActivity.codeSignInRequired()`, the private class in `MainActivity` called `CheckOrRetrieveCodeTask`, and `HaikuSession.getCodeSynchronous()` which calls the `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` method to get the one-time code.

Note that getting this code requires your user to see and accept the standard Google SignIn consent dialog.  Additionally, once you use the code once it is invalid (for security reasons) so make sure that your server saves the tokens that it gets from exchanging the code.

The [Haiku+ Java Server](https://developers.google.com/+/haikuplus/java) has a good example of how to exchange the authorization code for tokens.

Once you have the access token, you can call any Google APIs to which the user consented on the client.  The Haiku+ Java Server shows an example of this when it fetches the users circles.

Yes, this is a complicated flow but it is the best and most secure way to do this.  If you don't want to do all of this, I'd recommend submitting `Events` from the client.  The Google Play Games SDK for Android makes this very easy and automatically handles all of the caching and retry logic.